# macOS Sierra: Pulse Secure Client client broken

Tags: macos

Upgraded to macOS Sierra and found that the Pulse Secure Client is broken on the new OS.

```
Exception Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
Description: *** -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** -[ConsoleAppDelegate scriptRunningProc])
User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x9467521b __raiseError + 187
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9ed086e6 objc_exception_throw + 273
2   CoreFoundation                      0x94675135 +[NSException raise:format:] + 133
3   Foundation                          0x95c39441 -[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:] + 134
4   Foundation                          0x95c3938f +[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:] + 66
5   Junos Pulse                         0x000363b3 -[ConsoleAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 182
6   Foundation                          0x95c53ad8 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_2 + 32
7   CoreFoundation                      0x94576934 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
8   CoreFoundation                      0x94576824 _CFXRegistrationPost + 452
9   CoreFoundation                      0x94576576 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 54
10  CoreFoundation                      0x94534843 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1699
11  CoreFoundation                      0x9453367d _CFXNotificationPost + 637
12  Foundation                          0x95c0e8e4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 71
13  AppKit                              0x926ad513 -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 336
14  AppKit                              0x926ad243 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 232
15  AppKit                              0x925788c2 _DPSNextEvent + 2268
16  AppKit                              0x92c76ce9 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1423
17  AppKit                              0x92c76752 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 132
18  AppKit                              0x9256d17a -[NSApplication run] + 943
19  AppKit                              0x9253a299 NSApplicationMain + 1368
20  libdyld.dylib                       0x9f55a3b5 start + 1
```

If you use Pulse Secure Client on a Mac let me know how can this be resolved on Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install 5.2.5 and it should work again.  You can get it here: https://admin.kuleuven.be/icts/services/extranet/ps-pulse-mac-5-2r5-0-b869-installer.dmg

More info in Apple's discussion forum:  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49006